# How do I setup Spyder to highlight and auto-complete kivy files (.kv)?

Tags: python, kivy, spyder

How do I setup `Spyder` to highlight and auto-complete `kivy` files (`.kv`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spdyer dev here*) There is no way at the moment for Spyder to highlight kivy files, sorry :-(

Comment: thanks for the answer. Should I create an issue in the Spyder github to see this added in the future?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: None, sorry. Since Spyder is biased towards scientific computing, we're not interested on this.